# Filling textboxes sequentially from user-checked checkboxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I built a software to design safety stickers. There's a bunch of checkboxes to the left, which represent various hazards. I'd like to "link" those checkboxes to a group of textblocks, disposed in a grid.

[Checkboxes to be linked to textblocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrKQN.png)

If I check anyone of the checkboxes, the *first* empty textblock of the grid (i.e. the highest "cell" in the upper-left corner) shows the checkbox caption. If I check a second checkbox, the *second* empty textblock of the grid (i.e. the highest "cell" in the upper-right corner) shows the caption of that second checkbox... and so forth. The point of that section is to show a "live" overview of the chosen options, with a relevant logo (though I'd prefer to focus on the textboxes for now).

So the main problem is two-fold. Looping through all the checkboxes for any changes, and then reporting those changes in order, into the grid.

Here's what I could come up with. This activates whenever I check a certain checkbox.

The row and column info are in two arrays, so that the grid would fill from left to right, top to bottom. Then, two foreach loops scans for all checkboxes in grid #1 and all textblocks in grid #2.

When a certain checkbox is checked, the program gets its row and column from the respective arrays, and adds the textblock to the designed "cell" in the grid. It simply does not work.

```
void CheckBoxToModify()
{
    int[] row = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3 };
    int[] column = { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
         foreach (CheckBox c in grd1.Children.OfType<CheckBox>())
         {
             if (c.IsChecked == true)
             {
                 grdSIMDUT.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row[i]);
                 grdSIMDUT.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column[j]);
                 grdSIMDUT.Children.Add(t);
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `StackPanel`? It would do all that for you, you just have to tell it when to add and remove items. If you want to you could even use `TextBlock`s inside the `StackPanel`.

Comment: you can solve both problems by using two ItemsControls and a single collection as their ItemsSource. Each of them can use UniformGrid with two columns as ItemsPanel. The ItemTemplate for the first ItemsControl will contain CheckBox, for the second - only TextBlock

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dedicated data model to model an option.
Then use a `ListBox` to display the `CheckBox` items and a second `ListBox` to display the selected options overview.
Using a `UniformGrid`  as `ListBox.ItemsPanel` provides an easy way to display the items in columns.

When you use data binding, the task becomes very trivial:

**Option.cs**

```cs
public class Option : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Option(string title, Action selectionChangedCallback = null)
  {
    this.Title = title;
    this.SelectionChangedCallback = selectionChangedCallback;
  }

  private bool isSelected;
  public bool IsSelected
  {
    get => this.isSelected;
    set
    {
      this.isSelected = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
      this.SelectionChangedCallback?.Invoke();
    }
  }

  public string Title { get; }
  public Action SelectionChangedCallback { get; }

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  // The source collection for the CheckBox list
  public ObservableCollection<Option> Options { get; }

  // A view of the Options collections to avoid explicit item handling 
  // to track selected Option items.
  public ListCollectionView SelectedOptions { get; }

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    this.Options = new();

    // By defining a filter for this collection view,
    // we can force the collection view to contain particular items only.
    // In our case, we want it to contain selected Option items only.
    this.SelectedOptions = new ListCollectionView(this.Options)
    {
      Filter = option => (option as Option).IsSelected
    };

    for (int count = 1; count <= 6; count++)
    {
      this.Options.Add(new Option($"Option {count}", this.SelectedOptions.Refresh));
    }
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>

  <!-- The options selector view -->
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Options}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Option}">
        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>

  <!-- The selected options overview view -->
  <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedOptions}">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <UniformGrid Columns="2" />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
 
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Option}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>
</Window>
```